# How to reach cloned svg elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I used `<use xlink:href="path/to/file.svg">` element in my main svg file in order to clone repeatable block of svg few times.

index.svg:

```
    <g id="menu_items" transform="translate(0,110)">
       <use xlink:href="path/to/file.svg">
       <use xlink:href="path/to/file.svg">
       <!-- 10 times -->
    </g>
```

and file.svg contains:

```
<g>
   <text x="10" y="5" dx="5" dy="15" fill="navy" font-size="15">
    <!-- here I want to add something with javascript-->                     
   </text>
<g>
```

I tried to find element inside, but without results:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("text"); // gives []
```

How I can access svg elements cloned by  directive with JavaScript?

Comment: where is the javascript?

Comment: Js is included in index.svg

Comment: You can't access the `file.svg` DOM from `index.svg`, is there any particular reason why you need the elements in separate files?

Comment: I would like to reuse some svg blocks in my index.svg few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the use elements don't create actual clones, they create *conceptual clones* (it's as-if the elements were cloned visually). If you need real clones then you should do that with e.g `elm.cloneNode(true)`.

If you want to inspect the hierarchy constructed by a use element, see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGUseElement). The starting point would be `yourUseElm.instanceRoot`.

Anyway, it seems you could just move the elements you need from the external file into the main one - that way you'll naturally have access to the elements in the DOM. Another way is to load the external document with XMLHttpRequest, and insert actual clones where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access DOM elements with JavaScript if they were included with `<use>` directive.